# tengo error @endsection con esta parte y me vota este error el cual no entiendo

Tags: laravel-blade

me sale error en esa parte creo que esta mal el @endsection al momento de cerrar talvez
[image: me sale error en esa parte creo que esta mal el @endsection]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor no uses imágenes para compartir el código hace que sea difícil analizar el posible error, edita y pegalo como texto

Comment: El `endsection` no debe tener nombre, mira la [doc. oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade)

Comment: Agrega el codigo porfa

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer le cierre de una seccion en laravel unicamente usas `@endsection` sin especificar el nombre de la seccion.

Ejemplo:

```
@section('content')
  <h1>Hola mundo.</h1>
@endsection
```